# how to bin computed data by percentile in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, binning

I have a data frame that contains a large number of symbols, dates, and values

```
date         symbol value
2014-01-03     A      2.5
2014-01-04     A      3.1
2014-01-06     A      4.5
2014-01-03     B      2.6
2014-01-05     B      3.2
2014-01-06     B      4.3
```

I want to split the data by symbol, compute a percentage change for the 2 most recent dates, and bin the data by some variable number of groups where the 1st group has the largest set of pct. change, the next has the 2nd largest and so on. Each group needs to have approximately the same number of symbols.

Ideally, I would like my new data frame to look something like this

```
date         symbol value       pctchg     bin
2014-01-03     A      2.5       .45161      1
2014-01-04     A      3.1       .45161      1
2014-01-06     A      4.5       .45161      1
2014-01-03     B      2.6       .34375      2
2014-01-05     B      3.2       .34375      2
2014-01-06     B      4.3       .34375      2
```

This seems like a perfect task for ddply, but I'm struggling to get something to work.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for providing a small dummy data set and the desired results. Please note that people are generally much happier to help if you show the code you have already tried and what went wrong (see e.g. [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**here**)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an experienced coder, but I'll field this candidate:

```
df <- read.table(sep=" ", header=T, text="
date symbol value
2014-01-03 A 2.5
2014-01-04 A 3.1
2014-01-06 A 4.5
2014-01-03 B 2.6
2014-01-05 B 3.2
2014-01-06 B 4.3")

library(plyr)
df <- df[order(df$symbol, df$date),]
df <- ddply(df, "symbol", transform, pctchg=value[length(value)]/value[length(value)-1]-1)
df <- df[order(-df$pctchg),]

bins <- 2

library(ggplot2)
groups <- cut_number(1:length(unique(df$pctchg)), n=bins)
levels(groups) <- 1:length(levels(groups))
df <- merge(x=df, y=cbind.data.frame(symbol=unique(df$symbol), bin=groups))
df[order(-df$pctchg),]
#   symbol       date value    pctchg bin
# 1      A 2014-01-03   2.5 0.4516129   1
# 2      A 2014-01-04   3.1 0.4516129   1
# 3      A 2014-01-06   4.5 0.4516129   1
# 4      B 2014-01-03   2.6 0.3437500   2
# 5      B 2014-01-05   3.2 0.3437500   2
# 6      B 2014-01-06   4.3 0.3437500   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data.frame, `DF`, is already sorted by `symbol` and `date` as it is in the question, `f` computes the change of the last two values of its vector argument and `ave` applies that to each group.  Finally we use `order` to re-sort and we append `bin`.  We used the heading `relchg` rather than `pctchg` since the values shown in the question are not percents.

```
f <- function(x) { n <- length(x); if (n > 1) x[n] / x[n-1] - 1 else NA }
DF2 <- transform(DF, relchg = ave(value, symbol, FUN = f))
o <- with(DF2, order(-relchg, symbol, date))
transform(DF2[o, ], bin = as.numeric(factor(symbol, levels = unique(symbol))))
```

The result is:

```
        date symbol value    relchg bin
1 2014-01-03      A   2.5 0.4516129   1
2 2014-01-04      A   3.1 0.4516129   1
3 2014-01-06      A   4.5 0.4516129   1
4 2014-01-03      B   2.6 0.3437500   2
5 2014-01-05      B   3.2 0.3437500   2
6 2014-01-06      B   4.3 0.3437500   2
```

Comment: In the last line of code, I think that `bin` should be based upon `pctchg`, not `symbol`.

Comment: That could only be done if we knew that no two symbols have the same chg but we don't know that.  The way it is works more generally.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from LukeA's answer as a more canonical `plyr` solution.

If you are going to use `plyr`, call `arrange` rather than `order`.

```
df <- arrange(df, symbol, date)
```

The code for `pctchg` isn't quite right.  To match the output in the question, use

```
df2 <- ddply(
  df,
  .(symbol), 
  mutate, 
  pctchg = (value[length(value)] - value[length(value)-1]) / value[length(value)-1]
)
```

(Also note the use of `mutate` rather than `transform`. Bins can be generated using a hack based on the `factor` function.

```
mutate(df2, bin = as.integer(factor(-pctchg)))
```